# Reduce time to fill empty dataframe cells in Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have stocks dataset with over 10000+ columns and 1.5 million rows. Current code takes 8 days to execute. I want to bring it down to a couple of minutes/hours.

Dataframe is of stock data. Each stock has 5 columns associated with it. There are NaN values all over the dataset. I have a script ready to fill these NaN values.

I want the to do the following:
1. For all stocks, if open value find the last NaN and fill it with Close Value of the previous row. Continue this until you reach the last row. Code I have written is

My table looks likes

```py
0  S1 close | S1 high | S1 low | S1 open | S2 close |..S2 open....
1  100        123        98       100        350         361
2  100        103        98       102        350         361
3  Nan        Nan        Nan      Nan        350         361
4  Nan        Nan        Nan      Nan        350         361
5  100        101        98       100        349         351
```

S1, S2 are stock names. I have used the name 'open' to create a list of all open columns and iterate through them.

```py
open_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'open' in col]
for cols in open_cols:      
     j=df.columns.get_loc(cols)

     #Find all row index which have null value
     r=df[df[cols].isnull()].index.tolist()

     for var in r: 
        i=df.index.get_loc(var)
        df.iloc[i,j]= df.iloc[i-1,j-3]
        df.iloc[i,j-3]= df.iloc[i,j]
        df.iloc[i,j-2]= df.iloc[i,j]
        df.iloc[i,j-1]= df.iloc[i,j]
        df.iloc[i,j+1]= 0
```

Code works fine but takes too much time to process. I know there is a way to iterate rows in pandas using iterrows and .apply method but for my usecase I am failing to implement them. Expected output is as shown below

```
0  S1 close | S1 high | S1 low | S1 open | S2 close |..S2 open....
1  100        123        98       100        350         361
2  100        103        98       102        350         361
3  102        102        102      102        350         361
4  102        102        102      102        350         361
5  100        101        98       100        349         351
```

Comment: have a look at `ffill()` and `bfill()`, e.g.: `df['S1 open'] = df['S1 open'].ffill(); df = df.bfill(1)`.

Comment: Thanks Quang. Used ffill() in conjuction with fillna() to solve my problem :)

Comment: If it is solved could you close it?

Comment: You have answered it as a comment. Can't close until you post an answer